# PHP SQL query not updating values in database

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application, and one of the pages shows a table displaying information about particular accounts (sorted by AccountUserId).

I want to add two columns to this table, to allow the user to enter a `letter addressee name` & `preferred addressee name` to add these fields to the account.

I have made the relevant change in the database- added the columns `letterAddresseeName` & `preferredAddresseeName` to the account.account table- the two fields are only applicable to entries in the table whose `typeId` field has a value of '4' (this denotes that they are the person responsible for paying the account balance).

I added a couple of account users on the front end, and queried the database using SQL SMS, and I can see that the users exist in the account.account table (I ran a query searching for the names I had added for these accounts). However, although I had added data to the `letterAddresseeName` & `preferredAddresseeName` fields in the table, these fields were still blank in the database.

I'm trying to write the SQL I will need to update these fields, but having not really used SQL much over the last ten years or so, I'm a bit rusty with it.

In the AccountsController.php file, I've added the following function to the `AccountsController` class:

```
class AccountsController extends Controller
{
    use AccountsTrait;
    ...
    public function addAddresseesToAccount(Request $request)
    {
        $accountId = $request->input('accountId');
        $sqlArgs = [];
        $addAddresseesToAccountSQL = $this->addAddresseesToAccountSQL( $accountId, $sqlArgs );

        $addressees = DB::select(
            $addAddresseesSQL,
            $sqlArgs
        );
    }
    ...
    public functionaddAddresseesToAccountSQL($accountId, &$sqlArgs, $letterAddresseeName, $preferredAddresseeName)
    {
        $sqlArgs['accountId'] = $accountId;
        $addAddresseesSQL = "
            UPDATE ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT
            SET letterAddresseeName = $letterAddresseeName, preferredAddresseeName = $preferredAddresseeName
            WHERE accountId = $accountId;
        ";

        return $addAddresseesSQL;
    }
}
```

In the HTML for the fields I've added, I've set the `ng-change` attribute to call this PHP function:

```
<!--Letter Addressee Name -->
<td *ngIf="!responseData.loading" class="width-1 visible-lg-table-cell">
    <input type="text" name="letterAddresseeNameTextField" ng-value= getLetterAddresseeName(responseData) ng-change = "AccountsController.addAddresseesToAccount()"><br>

</td>

<!--Preferred Addressee Name -->
<td *ngIf="!responseData.loading" class="width-1 visible-lg-table-cell">
    <input type="text" name="preferredAddresseeNameTextField" ng-value = getPreferredAddresseeName(responseData) ng-change = "AccountsController.addAddresseesToAccount()" ><br>

</td>
```

What I am doing wrong here? Do I need to call the PHP function through an Angular function rather than calling it directly?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Since you're using Laravel, you really *must* avoid creating SQL statements by hand, especially when you just dump raw values into the query like that. What's wrong with using Eloquent here?

Comment: `public functionaddAddresseesToAccountSQL` declaration should be `public function addAddresseesToAccountSQL` (space after `function`). Hope this is a formatting error, or else lol

Comment: I'm very new to Laravel- I did know about Eloquent, but had forgotten that's what you're meant to use for SQL with Laravel... Thanks.